# Work with data in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have DataFrame like below:

```
date = pd.DataFrame({'inputDates':['2015-01-07', '2015-12-02', 
                                   '2005-01-03', '2016-11-13', 
                                   '2020-06-03']})
```

And I need to check for all of these dates:

- number of day in month - for example 07.01.2015 it is seventh day in month
- number of week in year - for example 07.01.2015 is 1st week in year
- number of month in year - for example 07.01.2015 is 1st month in year
- number of day in year - for example 07.01.2015 is the 7th day in year
- number of quarter in year for example 07.01.2015 is the 1st quarter in year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (see more in [the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) ):

```
date['inputDates'] = pd.to_datetime(date['inputDates'])

# day in month
date.inputDates.dt.day

# week in year
date.inputDates.dt.isocalendar().week

# month in year
date.inputDates.dt.month

# day in year
date.inputDates.dt.dayofyear

# quarter
date.inputDates.dt.to_period('Q-DEC').dt.quarter
```